# How to produce a coverage report from a visual studio .coverage file that is similar to the one produced by emma?

Tags: visual-studio, code-coverage

Visual Studio code coverage produces a .coverage binary file which can be converted to xml. Is there an xsl transform available that can convert that xml to a formatted report similar to the one produced by emma coverage tool for java. Any other transformations that would produce a meaningful report are also welcome.

Answer (score 3):

This tool can help: https://github.com/jsargiot/visual-coverage

This tool converts the .coverage file to clover or to a html report.

It's easy to use:

```
VisualCoverage.exe --input file.coverage --html report.html
```

I'm using it and the only problem (related to coverage files themselves) is that you need the folder with the binaries for the report to work, otherwise you'll get an "image not found" error.

Comment: This package does not seem to be maintained any more